# как показать текст, если на странице сайта не показалось изображение?

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, node.js

Как показать текст на сайте если по каким то причинам не показалось изображение определенного размера, либо баннер?
Знаю что есть некоторые догадки с использованием ABP как обойти блокировщик рекламы. Но в моем случае это не работает так как контент на странице выводится с помощью AJAX с другой страницы.
Перебрал и опробовал 5 примеров вывода изображения или текста при включенном блокировщике рекламы и из ни один не заработал. Пробовал разные варианты вставки кода и на ту страницу, с которой получает основная страница контент и наоборот на ту, на которой отображается.

Comment: `alt` аттрибут у тега `img` покажет на месте изображения текст, который вы там напишете. Правда будет не очень красиво

Comment: Я это знаю Но такой Вариант мне не подходит ))))) Мне нужен красивый текст в рамке Который сообщает пользователю что выключите блокировщик рекламы !

Comment: Результатом аякса будет урл для картинки? Отдавайте тег целиком. Пусть в блоке будет по дефолту ваш красивенький текст, а если `img` отдался - убирайте текст

Comment: Хорошо как это прописать Сам код  ? Потом банер у меня внизу а текст должен быть чуть выше ! Если банер не показан то вывести текст чуть выше ? Как это код выглядеть ?

Comment: https://github.com/sitexw/BlockAdBlock/blob/master/test.html Этот вариант мне бы подошел без картинки просто текст который говорит что блокировщик включен.  Но он не работает как не старался ! Проще всего да и без санкций всяких от поисковиков будет реагировать на картинку размером с банер и если она не показана на сайте то вывести текст выше или ниже без разницы просто в другом месте сайта !

Comment: Еще проще : Если img не загрузилось значит в блоке таком то текст ! Как это в js коде прописать ?

Comment: Хорошо как это прописать Сам код  ? Потом банер у меня внизу а текст должен быть чуть выше ! Если банер не показан то вывести текст чуть выше ? Как это код выглядеть ? Думал закрыть текст картинкой, чтоб текст под картинкой был. Но мне надо в другом месте его показать ! Помогите люди добрые !?